# SAS Studio-Dealing with Variable Names that have Spaces

Tags: sas, sas-studio

When I load in an excel sheet through `PROC IMPORT`, locally installed SAS automatically replaces the variable names with spaces to an underscore (_). Such as Patient ID will become `Patient_ID` and Health Records will become `Health_Records`.

However, when I load the same file in SAS Studio, that renaming convention isn't applied. So Patient ID and Health Records are kept as is...without the underscore in place.

Thus, how would I call these variables in SAS Studio? A syntax error pops when I try to call `IF Patient ID THEN this`. Would I have to physically add the underscore to my original dataset or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is caused by the setting of VALIDVARNAME option.

To refer to variable names with spaces you need to use a name-literal
for example.

```
"Patient ID"n
```

Quoted string followed by the letter N.

Answer (score 2):

As @data_null_ notes, `VALIDVARNAME=ANY` is what is causing this.

If you want SAS Studio to behave like your desktop SAS, simply add

```
options validvarname=v7;
```

to the top of your program (or to some program that will run before your imports, like an autoexec).  Then your underscores will return.